# squid authentication error kerberos - windows active directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, squid, kerberos, rhel6

I use squid on RHEL6 and I want that authentication is via AD windows 2008, I already joined the server to the windows domain and all users is already seen by wbinfo -u wbinfo -g but wbmin -t show error below :

$ wbinfo -t
checking the trust secret for domain TELMA via RPC calls failed
Could not check secret

I followed this tuto https://www.dalemacartney.com/2012/0...nd-simple-way/ and all is fine and normally all user on domain doesn't require authentication but when I configured the browser to point to the proxy it's always requiring authentication and showing error below on /var/log/squid/cache.log :

2014/07/31 15:47:07| squid_kerb_auth: ERROR: gss_acquire_cred() failed: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information. Unknown error
2014/07/31 15:47:07| squid_kerb_auth: INFO: User not authenticated
2014/07/31 15:47:07| authenticateNegotiateHandleReply: Error validating user via Negotiate. Error returned 'BH gss_acquire_cred() failed: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information. Unknown error'

This command also provides error below :

$ kinit -V -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_10084_H30tfi
kinit: Cannot determine realm for host (principal host/rhel6test@)

Find below my squid.conf configuration :

auth_param negotiate program /usr/lib64/squid/squid_kerb_auth 
auth_param negotiate children 10
auth_param negotiate keep_alive on

http_access deny !ad_auth
http_access allow ad_auth

Could someone help for this issue?

Comment: have you configure kerberos? sorry for the external link http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Kerberos

Comment: Yes, find below my kerberos config :

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = DOMAINE.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab

[realms]
 DOMAINE.COM = {
  kdc = tdcp02wp.domaine.com
  kdc = tdcp03wp.domaine.com
  kdc = tdcp01wp.domaine.com
  admin_server = tdcp02wp.domaine.com
  default_domain = domaine.com
 }
[domain_realm]
 .domaine.com = DOMAINE.COM
 domaine.com = DOMAINE.COM

[appdefaults]
 pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
 }

Comment: I already read this  wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Kerberos

Comment: if use the command kinit <one_of_user> , do you get the kerberos ticket?

Comment: find below recult command :
$ kinit tsioritafita
Password for tsioritafita@CORP.TELMA.MG:
[ RHEL6TEST | root | 2014-08-01 16:22:42 | /root ]
$ kinit -V -k -t /etc/squid/HTTP.keytab
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_10084_pN2aCW
kinit: Cannot determine realm for host (principal host/rhel6test@)

Comment: now use the klist?

Comment: $ klist -ekt /etc/squid/squid.keytab
Keytab name: WRFILE:/etc/squid/squid.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   3 07/31/14 10:46:22 RHEL6TEST$@CORP.TELMA.MG (arcfour-hmac)
   3 07/31/14 10:46:22 RHEL6TEST$@CORP.TELMA.MG (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 07/31/14 10:46:22 RHEL6TEST$@CORP.TELMA.MG (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   3 07/31/14 10:46:22 host/rhel6test.corp.telma.mg@CORP.TELMA.MG (arcfour-hmac)

Comment: Hi guys, wbinfo -u, wbinfo -g doesn't work now, it was working after I joined the server to the domain. please help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure reverse DNS lookup is properly configured for your domain as explained [here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/WindowsActiveDirectory#DNS_Configuration).

If you run `dig -x [domain_controler_ip]` and you don't see your domain name in the "ANSWER SECTION" you will get `Unspecified GSS failure`.